# DiscordJS Error, Embed Message Within Command Handler

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make my bot use an embed message however it will not work because i keep getting the Message not defined error

I have tried just using the author.bot but then it comes up with Author not defined, Something important to mention, I am using the command handler provided by the DiscordJS Guide and then i tried using the DiscordJS Guide for Embeds and it didnt work, thats basically how i ended up here

Code Below

````
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('embed')
        .setDescription('A W.I.P Embed'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        
        const Embed1 = new MessageEmbed().setTitle('Some title');
        
        if (message.author.bot) {
            Embed1.setColor('#7289da');
        }
    }
};```
````

Comment: You should learn basic javascript before attempting discord.js.

Comment: @Finbar Everyone starts at some point, there is no need to be rude. Instead of giving a rude comment, you could have suggested websites or links to help the user improve their code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using a `message` object when the exported item is: `interaction`.

Change:

```js
if (message.author.bot) {
  Embed1.setColor('#7289da');
}
```

to:

```js
if (interaction.user.bot) {
  Embed1.setColor('#7289da');
}
```

There is no `interaction.author` and only a `interaction.user`, therefore is the only way to check if it's a bot.